# Facebook send button to all friends

Tags: facebook

I just want to know is it possible to to use [send button of facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button) to send message to all the contacts?

I have seen many people have achieve that but is it even legal to do that?

Comment: Possible as in how many friends can the user add in the dialog that pops up, or …?

Comment: All facebook friends, but is it even legal?

Comment: Possible that Facebook has set some kind of limit on the number of friends the user can add, yes. (But if I wanted to share something with _all_ my friends, I could simply post it onto my timeline - why use the mechanism that is intended for _private_ messages in that case in the first place?)

Comment: That is true by all means, but consider this that I am trying to integrate this in one app and having the send button, now adding a script to send all is it legal?

Comment: That’s why I asked you if you meant a limit to the people _the user_ can select in the dialog. If you want to populate the recipients via script, of course that is not allowed. (But not even possible either, because the Send button gets rendered as an iframe, so that you have no access to it via JavaScript.)

Comment: So my use case is that I want to send message to all friends of a user (after granting permission), using fb send plugin its not possible, using js sdk it can be done, but sending message(mostly links for marketing) to all the friends would be spam according to me, so will fb allow me? BTW that is my clients requirement.

Comment: You can not send private messages via the API. Facebook provides this dialog only, on purpose. And users have to decide if they want to send a private message, and if so to whom. Your app is of course not allowed to specify the recipients for them. This would absolutely be spam.